# Update 1 column using bulkinsert C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

I have dataabase of 2.5 million records. One column in database is empty. Now i want to fill that column by inserting in Bulk, because a simple update query takes a lot of time. But the problem is that bulkinsert starts inserting record at the end, not from the start. Here is my code:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
{
     for (int j = 0; j < rows.Length; j++)
     {
         DataRow dailyProductSalesRow = prodSalesData.NewRow();                   
         string[] temp = ((string)rows[j]["Area"]).Split(new string[] { " ", "A","a" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
         if (Int32.TryParse(temp[0], out number))
         {
             int num1 = Int32.Parse(temp[0]);
             dailyProductSalesRow["Area1"] = 1;
         }
         else
         {
             dailyProductSalesRow["Area1"] = 0;
             Console.WriteLine("Invalid "+temp[0]);
         }
         prodSalesData.Rows.Add(dailyProductSalesRow);
     }
     s.DestinationTableName = prodSalesData.TableName;

     foreach (var column in prodSalesData.Columns)
     {
         s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
     }
     try
     {
         s.WriteToServer(prodSalesData);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: BulkInsert does an insert, not an update.

Comment: Why are you doing this in c# and not using a sql script?

Comment: I have to read data from file then perform some transformations and then insert it to database that's why doing in c#

Answer (score 1):

**If you need to update, use an `UPDATE` stamenet**

[BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) is designed to help make inserting many records faster as `INSERT` can be very slow and difficult to use when trying to get a large amount of data into a database.

`UPDATE` is already the fastest way of updating records in a database.  In your case I'd guess you want a statement a bit like this based on what your `BULK INSERT` is apparently trying to do.

```
UPDATE SalesData
SET Area1 = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Area, 0, CHARINDEX('A', Area)))
```

If you want to try and make it faster then try looking at [Optimizing Bulk Import Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  Some of the advice there (e.g. the recovery model used by the database) may also be applicable to `UPDATE` performance when updating many records.